# How to set Tor Browser as default browser in Ubuntu, please?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

I try to set tor web browser as default application in Ubuntu 18.04.
After that I have installed it via ppa...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahflee/ppa
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
```

I've tried the followings

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser gnome-www-browser /home/fabrizio/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_it/Browser/start-tor-browser 200
```

this last sudo two times to put it in automatic mode too.
But all of this has not been sufficient.
Do you have any idea, please?

Note: It seems really difficult to let appear Tor web browser in `Activities -> Settings -> Default Applications -> Web` ... it seems that appears only Firefox.